# Tinkerpop/Gremlin and a remote server

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I use Tinkerpop/Gremlin to query a remote graph database (OrientDB or Neo4J, the choice is still unclear).

The queries are multi-step, like this example:

```
g.v(1).out('likes').in('likes').out('likes').groupCount(m)
```

I am wondering: is there a network roundtrip at each step of the Gremlin query? Or, is the Gremlin query "compiled" into the native query language of my backend, then the native query is sent once through the network and results are streamed from the server back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Neo4jHaGraph` then it will work as you describe with network calls as each step requires them (i.e. the entire statement is not compiled and sent to the server).  I am unsure of the latest capabilities of the remote configuration for `OrientGraph` though I suspect it works in a similar fashion, making network calls as required at each step.

One of the reasons that [Rexster](http://rexster.tinkerpop.com) was developed was to allow Gremlin scripts to be sent to a server so that it could executed on an embedded implementation of the Graph (.e.g. `Neo4jGraph`).  In this way, network roundtrips would be reduced as execution of the traversal would occur within the same JVM.

All of the above applies to TinkerPop 2.x.  Looking forward to TinkerPop 3.x (not yet released), you will have Gremlin Server which replaces Rexster and allows for more efficient streaming of results back to calling clients.  It also enables the opportunity for vendors to optimize traversals like the one you provided as your example to be more efficient given an implementation.  It is yet to be seen just how that might apply to remote configurations, but it's interesting to think just what might be possible in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlg optimises some queries to reduce round trips.